# Error Paging - Echo to HTML Page

Tags: php, html, forms

**Hello,**

*I am wondering HOW I can have any and all errors (when the form is submitted) link to a general error page "Link an error.html". The php form I am using now, links to itself and is just an ugly page with no css formatting. Do I need the echos to link to an "error.html"?*

**I am working with the following HTML FORM :**

```
 <div id="contact">
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
        <label for="first_name">First <span class="red">*</span></label>

        <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
        <label for="last_name">Last <span class="red">*</span></label>

        <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
        <label for="email">Email <span class="red">*</span></label>

        <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
        <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>

        <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
        <label for="comments">Message <span class="red">*</span></label>

        <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message"><a href="mailto:infor@glustik.com">Email Form</a>
</form>
        </div>
```

**This is the PHP File that I am Using :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "info@glustik.com";
    $email_subject = "Project Quote Request";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- MY THANK YOU SUCCESS PAGE GOES HERE -->

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to show the form validation errors along with the form. That way the user will get direct feedback.

You can use an array for all error messages.

```
<?php

 $errors = array();

 if(!isset($_POST['email'])) {
 $errors['email'] = 'Email is required';
}
//similarly for other errors.
```

Now in the form

```
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
<label for="email">Email <span class="red">*</span></label>
<?= if(isset($errors['email'])) echo $errors['email'] ?>
```